# Having trouble sending messages from a Discord Bot

Tags: python, windows, discord

I'm currently trying to make a Discord bot using Python, to automate some boring stuff. I'm currently just trying to make something that will respond to a message, and then send something back.

My code is Here:

```
import discord



TOKEN = '(The correct Token, hidden for obvious reasons)'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        msg = 'Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message)
        await client.send(message.channel, msg)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

When I run this code, the bot appears online, and recognises when someone types !hello. However, Immediately after, it returns an error trying to send a message "AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send'"

I've been at this for a fair few hours at this point, and any hep would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

considering this has "!" at the beginning of it, instead of making this an on_message event, we can just turn this into a command by changing the following and make it more compact while doing so!.

original code:

```py
import discord



TOKEN = '(The correct Token, hidden for obvious reasons)'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        msg = 'Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message)
        await client.send(message.channel, msg)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

edited code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands #imports the commands module

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.command()
async def Hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Hello {ctx.message.author}')

#the rest is the same as your original code
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run('Token')
```

Hopefully that helps! Best of luck,
-Landon